# cmake + TARGET_LINKER_FILE + add_library(INTERFACE IMPORTED)

Tags: cmake, conan

We currently have a cmake to build our application, we also use an external library that is defined that way (I have no control on this, it is generated by a tool called Conan, that we don't own !)

```
add_library(CONAN_PKG::libgpkg INTERFACE IMPORTED)
```

Later, I need to retrieve the path of the generated `.lib` file, most of the time I use a command like this:

```
set(MERGE_LIBS ${MERGE_LIBS} $<TARGET_LINKER_FILE:libgpkg>)
```

I got this error message:

```
Error evaluating generator expression:

$<TARGET_LINKER_FILE:CONAN_PKG::sqlite3>

Target "CONAN_PKG::sqlite3" is not an executable or library.
```

Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: You use target `CONAN_PKG::libgpkg`, but the error message is about `CONAN_PKG::sqlite3` one.

Comment: As defined, the ``CONAN_PKG::xxxx`` target is an INTERFACE target, which means it is not mapped to a single artifact/library. A package can contain more than one library, or no library at all (in case of a header only package). If you need, you have the cmake variables defined when you included ``conanbuildinfo.cmake``, for the libraries names and the libraries paths. With them it is relatively easy to obtain the full paths, check the ``conan_find_libraries_abs_path()`` inside ``conanbuildinfo.cmake``

Comment: Also, it would be nice to know the use case of needing the full path of the dependency, the good thing about cmake targets is that they abstract away this need. Maybe a better forum to discuss this would be github issues of the conan repo, or the "conan" channel at CppLang slack team